# How to ensure a sourced script is available when using a docker image for GitLab CI?

Tags: docker, shell, gitlab-ci

I use custom docker images (mostly based on phusion) for GitLab CI alright. But sometimes an image requires sourcing a shell file to work properly (set `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc.).

When running an interactive shell from the docker image (e.g. `docker run -it <image_name> /bin/bash`), this can be fixed by simply adding the appropriate `source` command to `/etc/profile` or whatever. But it looks like the scripts in GitLab CI are not run in an interactive shell, and then the paths are not properly set up. I work around this by adding the `source` (or `.`) command to the GitLab CI script itself, but this is something image-specific, that should be in the image, not in the script.

Is there anything I can do that will effectively source the file directly on the image (or at least when GitLab CI runs the script on the image)? I could manually inspect what environment changes the sourced file introduces and put them in `ENV` instructions, but I'm looking for something less fragile when rebuilding the image from possibly updated sources.

Comment: Do you have a specific Dockerfile that has a problem?  In Docker, it's almost always "safe" to install software directly into the  normal system directories, since the container filesystem is isolated from everything else and an image contains only one application; that would get around the need to set these environment variables.

Comment: @DavidMaze But I'm using shared runners for GitLab CI, so I can't install anything in their system. (Besides, as far as I understand it, the script is run inside the container (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html), so I'm not sure I could access the host filesystem anyway.) An example: https://gitlab.com/Molcas/Dockerfiles/-/blob/intel-patch/intel-phusion/Dockerfile (with which I need to run `. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh intel64` in the script).